# "rubygem mysql error: gem is not loaded" after CentOS upgrade

Tags: ruby, centos

I am upgrading a system from EL 6 to EL 7.  We have an application that uses ruby to setup a MySQL database. I know very, very little about ruby and gems, so I'm struggling getting this going.  Under EL 6, the setup process works properly.  Under CentOS 7, I get the following error when processing the rakefile:

> Specified 'mysql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add
>   `gem 'mysql'` to your Gemfile

Under 6, I don't see any MySQL gem files installed using `gem list`, but the setup process works fine and generates our database properly.

Under 7, I can manually run:  `gem install mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config`.
Then, the setup script works.

I am installing most of the required gems/ruby applications via `rpm`.

I have:

```
ruby-2.0.0.648-29.el7.x86_64
rubygem-rake-0.9.6-29.el7.noarch
rubygem-activesupport-4.2.5.2-2.fc24.noarch
rubygems-2.0.14.1-29.el7.noarch
rubygem-activemodel-4.2.5.2-1.fc24.noarch
rubygem-activerecord-4.2.5.2-1.fc24.noarch
ruby-mysql-2.8.2-1.el7.x86_64
```

ruby-mysql creates `/usr/local/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/mysql.so`.

Is the `mysql.so` library what provides the MySQL adapter or is there something else that effectively provides the mysql gem?  It's confusing that I don't have to do anything in EL 6 but have to install it specifically in EL 7.

Is this a pathing issue or a major change in source?  I'm obviously pulling in the activesupport and activerecord rpms from Fedora, so I suppose there could be a conflict there, but it's very hard to tell.

My `database.yml` file looks like this:

```
adapter: mysql
encoding: utf8
database: mydatabase
username: root
password:
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 3306
```

Comment: If there is a Gemfile, you would normaly call `gem install bundler; bundle install` to setup the environment.

Comment: I cannot locate any gem file(s) relating to mysql on the el6 system or the el7 system.  Actually, I see no references in any of the scripts to the calling of "gem".  I only have the Rakefile and database.yml plus the ruby migrate scripts.  I feel like one of the rpms, activerecord maybe, is doing something magic and uses it's own mysql adapter.

Comment: The Gemfile would be in the root of the script and ist called `Gemfile`.

Comment: there was none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure why there was never a gemfile in the original script.  As mentioned in my OP, a basic solution was to run gem install mysql, but that was weird because previously  it wasn't necessary.

What I think was happening:
Under EL6, the ruby-mysql rpm was putting the mysql.so in the proper location and basically issuing a gem install command.  The EL7 version I have was not calling the proper setup macros in the rpm.

What I did to fix this:
i used gem2rpm (such a great rpm/package) to generate the rubygem-mysql spec file.

https://github.com/fedora-ruby/gem2rpm

gem2rpm --fetch mysql (to get the gem)
gem2rpm -T > rubygem-mysql.spec.template
gem2rpm -t rubygem-.spec.template mysql-2.9.1.gem > rubygem-mysql.spec

You have to modify the spec file a bit after it's generated, then use that to spec template to properly build the spec file for your needs.

Then just use rpmbuild to actually make the rpm/srpm.

gem list now shows mysql in there and the setup script works.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the `mysql2` gem instead:

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

and database.yml:

```
adapter: mysql2
```

Hope that would help.

Comment: I don't think I have a gem file  If there's one, I can't locate it.

Comment: if you are not using a Gemfile, you can try `gem install mysql2` instead and see if that helps.